# Navigation for slider by checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button, slider

Continuing experiments with my own slider. Now making nav arrows. So Im asking how to make it work? I’m using next()/prev() to make next/prev input checkbox to be checked. But next()/prev() isn’t working. Why?
[Here](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/eNWEvM) is the code.

```
$('.to-right').click(function(){
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').next('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", true)
});
$('.to-left').click(function(){
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').prev('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", true)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.next()`

> Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

so your code `$('input[type="radio"]:checked').next('input[type="radio"]')` will not get the next radio button.

you can try :

```
$('.to-right').click(function(){
   $('input[type="radio"]:checked').next().next('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", true);
   // first next() will get <div class="slider-content">....</div> in your code
});
```

**same with `.prev()`**

> edit

======================================================

add class `first` and `last` to the first and last radio

```
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="1-1" class='first'> 
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="1-5" class='last'>
```

and hide the `to-left` nav at first

check this  **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpWXvE)**

Comment: Aha, I see now, so its not jumping to the next input checkbox, because the div is on its way. Thanks! Is it possible to hide the nav arrow wnen it goes to end of  "slider"?

Comment: Can you help me where to start to search for this solution?